# SSAS Dimension Attributes are not visible in Cube Browser (BIDS)

Tags: ssas, cube, olap-cube, ssas-2008, cubes

I am new to SSAS & Modifying the existing SSAS Cube to Add New Columns, Rename and Delete Existing Columns.

I Made required changes in the Data Source.

I Refreshed the Data Source View and able to see the new changes.

I Added the new columns in the Dimension by drag and drop from DSV Dimension Table. Deleted the Unnecessary/ Error Columns. I created Required Measures in Fact Table by Selecting Required Columns from the DSV Fact Table.

When I browse the cube from BIDS I can only see the attributes and measure which were available before I made changes. But not the latest changes. I did not deploy the cube into server.

Where do I need to make changes for this to view the New Changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by sdlaursen, your changes will not reflect to the cube until you deploy and then process the cube.

Any structural change to the cube is not reflected until you deploy it, process a cubes only refreshes the data, and not the structure of the cube.

Answer (score 0):

You can only observe your changes when browsing the dimensions etc. in BIDS if you in fact have deployed and processed your cube/ssas database to reflect your changes. There is no other way. If you do not want overwrite your production cube, you can choose to deploy to a different TEST database by temporarily changing deployment server/database in your BIDS project.